# AS3: is-not keyword?

Tags: actionscript-3, comparison, keyword

I can't seem to actually find a reference to 'is' in the AS3 documentation for type comparison other than [in examples](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8a.html). Perhaps this can't be done, but it seems like there should be something for this scenario...

Right now I have:

```
if ( event.target is Class )
{           
}
else
{
    // What I really want to do!
}
```

This seems silly because what I really want to say is...

```
if ( event.target isNot Class )
{
    // Sure would be cleaner!
}
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Shurdoof already provided the correct answered. I just wanted to say, this code smells. There's definitely a cleaner and safer alternative.

Comment: How do you mean, if you don't mind clarifying?

Comment: Documentation for ActionScript 3.0 `is` operator is here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#is

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
if ( !(event.target is Class) )
{           
}
```

Comment: I doubt you'll find another way. 'is' returns a boolean true or false, why would they also provide 'isnot' which would essentially do the same thing! :)

Comment: @adamk. You're right in that there isn't another way. But it wouldn't be complete non sense to have something like `isNot` or `is not`. After all, we've got `==` already, so we could do without `!=` and just go `if(!(a == b))` (at the price of making code uglier, I guess).

Comment: @Juan: That was my original thinking.

Comment: parentheses are crucial here. `!(object is Object)` is different than `(!object is Object)`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the class of an object:

```
var targetClass:Class = Object(event.target).constructor;
```

To test if target is not a textfield for example

```
if(Object(event.target).constructor != TextField){
   //not a textfield
}
```